# NSF proposal dwell time during COVID19 pandemic

Tags: nsf

I would like to hear your experience in the dwell time of the current NSF merit review process during the COVID19 crisis.  Per NSF data, they met their 75% performance goal to provide a decision within 6 months for the past years (except for 2017, due to the relocation to new headquarters).

Our proposal (in the CS discipline) was submitted in November 2019. It's now almost 8 months but still, no acceptance or rejection.  As far as I know, the review panel has already met, but nothing else.  Anyone facing a similar situation?  Thanks :)

Comment: Last similar plague situation was probaly before NSF existed so who can guess.

Comment: You should contact your NSF program officer to ask when decisions are likely to be made.  Anecdotally, it appears that NSF review processes have slowed down during the pandemic.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard from a colleague for an NSF DUE that it has been 8 months and they have not received any news yet.